# High MySQL Queries on Wordpress Site

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Thanks in advance for any help :)  I recently built a wordpress site that is a paid membership site that gives members access to back end free tickets.  The site is mainly run with s2member pro plugin and event espresso pro plugins.  I have 11 versions of the site running right now with about 2-3k members per site.

I ran p3 plugin profiler and got these stats for one of the sites.

*Visits:     7

*Number of PHP ticks:    20,345 calls avg.

*Memory Usage:   61.46 MB avg.

*MySQL Queries:  522 queries avg.

I am fairly new to this world and based on my research that sounds very high.  My questions are, are these numbers really high and what is a good range to be in?  How would I go about diagnosing what is causing this/fixing the issue (if its even an issue)?

I'm just worried something is doing too much work and that we run a risk of the sites slowing down and crashing.

Server stats for the 11 sites

Server load 0.35 (4 CPUs)

Memory Used 39.26% (1,511,712 of 3,850,268)

Swap Used   35.1% (701,976 of 1,999,864)

Thanks again for any help.